# Hacer lo que hago en MySQL pero en PDO con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de aprender *PDO*, manejo *PHP,* pero con *mysql_query* quise migrar a *PDO*, pero da un error, ya probé insertando pero no me funciona ahora, quiero probar haciendo una consulta pero no me sale alguien sabría el porque no me deja consultar.

El error que me sale es:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PDOJEFFERSON\models\agregarUser.php on line 5

Código:

```
function ConexionMySql(){
    $cadenaHost='mysql:Server=localhost;dbname=basebyjefferson';
    $nombre_user_db='root';
    $pass_user_db='';
    try {
        $conectar=new PDO($cadenaHost,$nombre_user_db,$pass_user_db);
        $conectar->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
<?php
    include '../conexion.php';
    $cn=ConexionMySql();
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM tbluser";
    $query = $cn->query($sql);
    while($r=$query->fetch()){
        echo json_encode($r);
    }
?>
```

Comment: intente no escribir el texto en mayusculas, si no es necesario. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios errores que solucionar.

Por una parte, creo recordar que la `dsn` `mysql:Server=` es errónea. Debería ser `mysql:host=`. Con `mysql:Server=localhost` da un poco igual por que es ignorado por `PDO`y usa el `default` que es `mysql:host=localhost`, pero si quieres conectar a una base de datos externa mediante una ip concreta igual te daría errores.

En segundo lugar, la función debe de retornar la instancia de la conexión para continuar trabajando con ella. Si no, retorna un valor nulo, y por lógica, al no "existir" la conexión, el script lanzará el error correspondiente.

```
<?php

function ConexionMySql()
{
    // $cadenaHost = 'mysql:Server=localhost;dbname=basebyjefferson';
    // cambiar por:
    $cadenaHost     = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basebyjefferson';
    $nombre_user_db = 'root';
    $pass_user_db   = '';
    try {
        $conectar = new PDO( $cadenaHost, $nombre_user_db, $pass_user_db );
        $conectar->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
    catch( Exception $e ) {
        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $conectar;
}


include dirname(__DIR__) . '/conexion.php';

$cn    = ConexionMySql();
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM tbluser";
$query = $cn->query( $sql );

while( $r = $query->fetch() ) {
    echo json_encode( $r );
}
```

PD.: No lo he probado. Si hay errores, un comentario y seguimos.

Comment: Muchas mi amigo es verdad lo que tu dices ya que si no retorna la conexion esta volviendo un valor null.
De antemano muchsa gracias por tu respuesta muy objetiva lo unico que agregue fue el [return $ conectar] y me hizo la consulta, me disculpo por la ignoracia sobre la pregunta estoy comenzando manejo PHP a la antigua y esto del PDO me llamo la atencion mucho y le estoy metiendo fe a esto jejej bueno muchas gracias Oscar R.

Answer (score 1):

tu problema esta en que tu función de conexión no te esta regresando una instancia de la base de datos.

Lo que te falta agregar a tu código de conexión es un `return` para obtener la instancia a la base de datos.

```
function ConexionMySql(){
   $cadenaHost='mysql:Server=localhost;dbname=basebyjefferson';
   $nombre_user_db='root';
   $pass_user_db='';
       try {
         $conectar=new PDO($cadenaHost,$nombre_user_db,$pass_user_db);
         $conectar->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         return $conectar;
       } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu ciclo esta mal hecho. Debería ser así:

```
foreach ($query as $querys)
{
    echo json_encode($r);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en tu función `ConexionMySql`, no está devolviendo valor alguno.

Intenta agregar:

```
return $conectar;
```

Antes de terminar la función, puede ser adentro de la sección `try`.

Por otro lado, en el código de `agregarUser.php` deberías comprobar que el valor que regresa la función `ConexionMySql` es válido antes de utilizarlo, por ejemplo:

```
if ($cn != null) {
    $query = $cn->query($sql);
} else {
    echo "¡Objeto PDO es nulo!";
}
```